# Prometheus: Metric from pod not found in Prometheus

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus

I am currently running metrics server inside my pod. The data is being sent inside pod at localhost:9090. I am able to get the data inside pod via curl. The deployment.yaml is annotated to scrape the data, but I don't see any new metrics in pod. What am I doing wrong?

metrics I see inside pod :

```
cpu_usage{process="COMMAND", pid="PID"} %CPU
cpu_usage{process="/bin/sh", pid="1"} 0.0
cpu_usage{process="sh", pid="8"} 0.0
cpu_usage{process="/usr/share/filebeat/bin/filebeat-god", pid="49"} 0.0
cpu_usage{process="/usr/share/filebeat/bin/filebeat", pid="52"} 0.0
cpu_usage{process="php-fpm:", pid="66"} 0.0
cpu_usage{process="php-fpm:", pid="67"} 0.0
cpu_usage{process="php-fpm:", pid="68"} 0.0
cpu_usage{process="nginx:", pid="69"} 0.0
cpu_usage{process="nginx:", pid="70"} 0.0
cpu_usage{process="nginx:", pid="71"} 0.0
cpu_usage{process="/bin/sh", pid="541"} 0.0
cpu_usage{process="bash", pid="556"} 0.0
cpu_usage{process="/bin/sh", pid="1992"} 0.0
cpu_usage{process="ps", pid="1993"} 0.0
cpu_usage{process="/bin/sh", pid="1994"} 0.0
```

deployment.yaml

```
  template: 
    metadata:
      labels: 
        app: supplier-service
      annotations:
        prometheus.io/path: /
        prometheus.io/scrape: 'true'
        prometheus.io/port: '9090'



          ports: 
            - containerPort: 80
            - containerPort: 443
            - containerPort: 9090
```

prometheus.yml

```
global:
  scrape_interval: 15s # By default, scrape targets every 15seconds. # Attach these labels to any time series or alerts when #communicating with external systems (federation, re$
  external_labels:
    monitor: 'codelab-monitor'
# Scraping Prometheus itself
scrape_configs:
- job_name: 'prometheus'
  scrape_interval: 5s
  static_configs:
  - targets: ['localhost:9090']
- job_name: 'kubernetes-service-endpoints'
  scrape_interval: 5s
  kubernetes_sd_configs:
  - role: endpoints
  relabel_configs:
  - action: labelmap
    regex: __meta_kubernetes_service_label_(.+)
  - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_namespace]
    action: replace
    target_label: kubernetes_namespace
  - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_pod_annotation_prometheus_io_scrape]
    action: keep
    regex: true
  - source_labels: [__address__]
    action: replace
    regex: ([^:]+)(?::\d+)?
    replacement: $1:9090
    target_label: __address__
  - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_service_name]
    action: replace
    target_label: kubernetes_name
```

Port numbers are correct. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Your `kubernetes_sd_configs` is configured to look for `endpoints`, which are created by services. Do you have an endpoint created for your service? You could check with `kubectl get endpoints` in your namespace. If you don't want to create a service, I suppose you could configure Prometheus to scrape pod targets too, check [the docs](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/configuration/configuration/#kubernetes_sd_config) for more info.

Also the [documentation for metrics and labels](https://prometheus.io/docs/concepts/data_model/#metric-names-and-labels) say the metric name must match the regular expression `[a-zA-Z_:][a-zA-Z0-9_:]*`, so the dash (`-`) in your metric name might be an issue too.

Comment: I have updated with the specifications you mentioned. And updated the main post as well. Can u please have a look once? prometheus.yml is also updated. Still no metrics on prometheus side. Is there any command to probe the Kubernetes system, where I can which metrics are sent from which pod?

Comment: Btw, I am not running pushgateway or prometheus-operator.... just Prometheus and grafana. :-)